# Где моя ошибка в функции-конструкторе?

Tags: javascript

```js
function User(name) {
this.name = name;
this.name2 = name2;
}

let user =  new User("Вася");
let name2 = new User("Коля");


alert(user.name);    // Выводит Вася
alert(user.name2);  //  Должно выводить Коля, но я допустил ошибку.                          
                   //   Где моя ошибка(?
```

Comment: а если нужно вставить допустим age, https://codepen.io/Viperx/pen/LYprmLj

Comment: Встала ошибка(((

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/bGVKMqZ - нету ошибок

Comment: Благодаря вам я понял, в чем были мои ошибки)
Вот финальный код: https://codepen.io/Viperx/pen/RwWJyzE

Comment: Спасибо добрый господин)

Comment: молодец - раз вопрос решён - удали его - минус спишется

Comment: По политике этого сайта, нельзя удалять вопросы,
так как они могут помочь и другим новичкам)

Comment: @Black_Viper, не так, **если** вопросы могут помочь другим новичкам, тогда их не надо удалять.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя ошибка в конструкторе, нет name2 в параметрах функции.

```
function User(name, name2) {
    this.name = name;
    this.name2 = name2;
}

let user =  new User("Вася", "Коля");
alert(user.name);
alert(user.name2);
```

Comment: Вот правильный ответ: https://codepen.io/Viperx/pen/RwWJyzE

Comment: @Black_Viper, не согласен, у вас в вопросе другое написано. Нельзя вопрос по ходу решения менять на другой

Comment: Он сильно и не отличается от первоначального вопроса, только там добавилось age и все)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function User(name) {
this.name = name;
//this.name2 = name2; - это не нужно
}

let user =  new User("Вася");
let name2 = new User("Коля");


alert(user.name);    // Выводит Вася
alert(name2.name);  //  Вот тут была неточность. Сейчас выводит Коля
```

Comment: this.name2 = name 2;  нужно для правильного оформления)))

Comment: хозяин барин :))

Comment: Вот правильный код:  https://codepen.io/Viperx/pen/RwWJyzE

Его лично проверял опытный разработчик по имени Максимка.

Comment: понятно, но в своём коде ты передаёшь один параметр в функцию, соответственно, то что я за комментировал никогда не выполнится.
а так да, максимка прав :)

Comment: Максимка всегда прав!